# VS 2015: C# NuGet Package restore failed. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C# project consuming packages from NuGet. The solution contains several C# projects and is checked out on drive C.

***Problem***: I cannot compile the solution or restore nuget packages since several hours. I get the following error:

> NuGet Package restore failed for project ...: The file or directory is
>   corrupted and unreadable.

The **Package Manager Console** reports the following error after startup:

> The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Restarting Visual Studio does not fix the issue. Accessing the files with File Explorer and Notepad++ works. I don't experience any internet connectivity issues. [Nuget](https://status.nuget.org/) seems to be online.

There is no private nuget registry in use, the  default package source `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` is used.

Visual Studio 2015 Professional 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.6.0.2511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> VS 2015: C# NuGet Package restore failed. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Please try the following troubleshootings to fix this issue:

- Remove all nuget packages under `\packages` folder, then go to the solution in Visual Studio and press "Restore Nuget Packages", rebuild your solution.
- Go to Tools->Extensions and Updates->Installed, uninstall the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015, and reinstall it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It may be the file system error in the drive

I use system drive tool to check and fix the error
[windows file system error check tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQ0F.png)